# Regex For Letters and Numbers Within URL

Tags: regex, go, url, goquery

I'm trying to match some URLS as a proof of concept using Golang. I'm not the best with regular expressions, I need something that matches anything with either a season number or episode number following a backslash. Here's an example:

```
https://URL.com/program/something-a/s1/e1/title
https://URL.com/program/something-a/e12/title
```

The seasons can go up to double figures (`/s12`, `/s13`), and the episodes up to three (e.g. `/e100`). What's the best way to do this?

Edit: So here's what I tried so far:

```
(\/s.\/)
```

or

```
(\/e.\/)
```

Seems to work for single figures, but not when you get up to something like `/e12/` etc. When I try to find something that matches both, like

```
(\/s[0-9][0-9]\/)
```

it doesn't pick up episodes or series with only a single number (e.g. `/s2/`).

Comment: Is `something-a` variable in practice?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `something-a` is variable, yes

Comment: `s[0-9]+` should match numbers both single and double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s(\d{1,2})/e(\d{1,3})
```

how it works

- s  matches letter s
- ( start of submatch capture group
- \d  match a single digit
- {1,2}   at least 1 no more than 2 of the previous expression (which is a digit)
- )   end of capture group
- /  literal slash character
- e matches letter e

...and then there is another sequence but for 3 digits, not 2